# Clicking "close" on a proposal in beta does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, vote-to-close, beta-phase

Obviously you shouldn't be able to close a proposal in beta, but I think it would be less confusing if the close button was hidden on beta proposals or displayed an error message when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good point. We removed the edit/delete/close/flag links for proposals in beta.